# Third hardest question on a hospital IQ test(Fill the blank)

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

> Place the numbers 1 through 9 in the available input boxes so that the
>   results of performing the mathematical operations in any row and
>   column (from left to right and top to bottom) always equals 13.
>
> \begin{bmatrix}\square&+&\square&-&\square\\
>  -& &+& &\times\\ \square&\times&\square&+&\square\\
>  +&&-&&+\\ \square&\times&\square&-&\square\\ \end{bmatrix}

It takes me an hour to solve this. Do you have an easy way to solve this? Let's explore.

[Original image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOKS7.png)

Comment: Well, a+b-c =13 means a+b > 14 so a,b> 5 so squares 1,2,5,7 must be 4 of the 5,6,7,8,9.  So square 4,  must be less than 3 or 1 or 2. If it's 2 we must have 4,5,6 = 2  x 5 + 3.  So 2,5,8 must be 9+5-1.  But then 7,8,9 = a x 1 - b is impossible.  So 4=1 and 6 is 5 or more so 1,2,5,6,7 = 5-9.  And 3,8,9 = 2-4.  From there trial and error shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

My eye settled on the middle row and right column, which have the same pattern of operators.  There aren't too many ways to make $13$ in that pattern.  Looking down the first column, the first multiplicand of the middle row is subtracted, so it wants to be small, and I will assume that the first number in the second row is smaller than the second.  This gives the second row as one of $149, 158, 167, 176,185,194,237,245,253,261,341$.  These are also the possibilities for the third column, though the first two numbers could be switched.  Starting down the list, each of $149,158,167,176$ fail because they require a $1$ in the top of the third column to match one we have used.  If it is $185$ the third column needs to be $253$ and the other two numbers in the top row have to sum to $15$ and be $69$ as we have used $8$.  They can't be $96$ because the middle bottom would have to be $1$ and $69$ fails because the bottom left needs to be $8$.  We go on to $194$ where the right column is $245$.  Again the top two need to sum to $15$ but now they must be $78$.  The order $78$ doesn't work because of the center bottom, which would have to be $4$, but $87$ works.  We are done with $$\begin {array} &8&7&2\\1&9&4\\6&3&5 \end {array}$$

Answer (score 2):

I tried it a bit, and my answer for this is $$8 \ \ 7 \ \ 2$$$$1 \ \ 9 \ \ 4$$ $$6 \ \ 3 \ \ 5$$
My approach was to notice that for $z$ in $x+y-z = 13$, $z$ can only be $1,2,3,4$, meaning the middle-left and bottom-middle ones could only be one of these four, and went on from there.

Answer (score 1):

Label spaces A through I.

A+B, B+E,A+G are all at least 14.  So A,B,E, and G are all greater than or equal to 5.

D x E must be less than 13 and E is 5 or more so D = 1 or 2.

If D=2 then E=5.  If E = 5 then B+5-H=13 so B=9, H=1.  So Gx1 -I =13 is impossible.

So D isn't 2.  So D=1.  So E+F = 13,  so F is at least 4.  C x F +I = 13 but F is at least 4 and I is at least 3 and C is at least 2.

If C is at least 3 then CxD+I is at least 14 so C is at most 2 and at least 2.  So C is 2 and I is at least 3.

2x F + I =13 and F is at least 4 so we have either 2x4 + 5.  Or 2x5 +3.

If F=4, I=5, E=9.  GxH = 18 and neither G or H is 9 so G and H are 3 and 6.  And G is at least 5 so G = 6, H =3 and B+9-3=13 so B=7.  That leaves A =8.  And that works as A+7-2=13 and A-1+6=13.

That's a solution.

any other solution would have F=5 and I =3 and E=8.

So A+B=11, GxH= 16, A+G=12, B-H=5. 1,2,3 are assigned so G and H are at least 4, so G xH =16 is impossible.

So only solution is

A=8,B=7,C=2,D=1,E=9,F=4,G=6,H=3,I=5.

Comment: My answer is 7    8    2

Comment: 7    8     2, 1      7     6, 7     2      1

Comment: Your answer uses 7 3 times, 1 twice and 2 twice and never uses 3,5, 5 or 9.

Comment: The original image says the word "to" instead of "through", misunderstanding